# How to configure Snowflake to send logs to Azure Log Analytics

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

Expert,
How can we configure Azure/Snowflake to access all snowflake logs using Azure Log Analytics and use kusto and alert to create alert?

Rana

Comment: Hi Rana, welcome to SO. Can you please post what you have already tried/researched?

Answer (score 2):

it depends what data you want to unload from Snowflake to log files, as there is lots of information available in account_usage and information schema. But it's easy enough to write that data out to files on Azure storage, for ingestion and use in Azure Log Analytics. Here's an example - pushing errors recorded in the login_history view to JSON files:

```
copy into @~/json_error_log.json from
    (select object_construct(*) from (
        select event_timestamp, event_type,user_name,reported_client_type,error_code,error_message
        from table(information_schema.login_history(dateadd('days',-7,current_timestamp()),current_timestamp()))
        where error_code is not null
    order by event_timestamp))
file_format = (type ='JSON');
```

And you can find more information here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-azure.html

Can't comment on the A.L.A tool operations but hopefully this gives you some idea of what to do on the Snowflake side.

Comment: Thank You for your Answer, but this approach will help me to push snowflake table contents to Azure storage and then log analytics or some other tables,
1. Do we have an approach to pull data from snowflake tables logs?
2. Do we have an approach to configure snowflake only to keep sending logs to file that's on Azure data lake/blolb?

Comment: What do you mean by "snowflake tables logs" - are you talking about change data capture? Snowflake doesn't make log files available externally - instead it writes information about its operations to admin tables/views and you have to explicitly unload that data to file in order to have it as physical log files. But yes you could set up an automated TASK in Snowflake to have this process (copy from table to file) write to Azure storage.